# Deactivate keyboard control in sap.ui.commons.Toolbar control

Tags: sapui5

Is there any way to deactivate the keyboard support of the [Toolbar control](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#test-resources/sap/ui/commons/demokit/Toolbar.html)?

When I click in a [text field](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#test-resources/sap/ui/commons/demokit/TextField.html) in my Toolbar, I would like the `arrow left`and `arrow right` keys to move my cursor in the text field left and right instead of jumping to the next control in the toolbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just override `onsapnext` and `onsapprevious` to stop TextField's parent from handling arrow event when it is in Toolbar's navigation items. Please check and run the code snippet.

```html
<script src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" id="sap-ui-bootstrap" data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal" data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"></script>
<script id="view1" type="sapui5/xmlview">
    <mvc:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:layout="sap.ui.commons.layout" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.ui.commons" controllerName="test.controller" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <Toolbar id="tb">
            <Button text="Button1"/>
            <TextField id="tf1" value="Toolbar Arrow Deactivated "/>
            
            <TextField id="tf2" value="Toolbar Arrow Activated "/>
            
            <Button text="Button2"/>
        </Toolbar>
    </mvc:View>
</script>
  
<script>
    sap.ui.controller("test.controller", {

        onInit: function() {
          var tf1 = this.getView().byId("tf1");

        
          tf1.onsapnext =  function(oEvent) {
              this._checkCursorPosForNav(oEvent, true);
          };
          
          tf1.onsapprevious = function(oEvent) {

        this._checkCursorPosForNav(oEvent, false);
       }

        },

    });


    var myView = sap.ui.xmlview("myView", {
        viewContent: jQuery('#view1').html()
    }); // 
    myView.placeAt('content');
</script>

<body class='sapUiBody'>
    <div id='content'></div>
</body>
```